# Twitter search with nested AND and OR?

Tags: api, search, twitter

I want to use the Twitter search API to find tweets that contain:

```
(keyword1 OR keyword2)

AND

(keyword3 OR keyword4)
```

In other words, there should always be a keyword from the first set, and a keyword from the second set. Is this possible using Twitters standard search API?

I have read the documentation but this kind of search isn't really mentioned.